How to preload fonts with Nuxt3?
I'm trying to preload my custom fonts with Nuxt3 to avoid flickering of the font change on page load, because it is generating a CLS problem. This is how I include my fonts currently in the config file:
css: [
        '~/assets/css/fonts.css',
        'vuetify/lib/styles/main.sass',
        '~/assets/global.css',
    ],

In Nuxt2 I had the following option in the config file to do this:
render: {
        bundleRenderer: {
            runInNewContext: false,
            shouldPreload: (file, type) => {
                return ['script', 'style', 'font'].includes(type)
            }
        }
    },

But it doesn't work in Nuxt3. I have also tried to import it to the head of the app.vue file:
useHead({
    link: [
        {
            rel: 'preload',
            type: 'font/woff2',
            href: '/fonts/font.woff2',
            as: 'font',
            crossorigin: true
        },
]})

But it also doesn't help, the font swap is still visible and causing CLS issue
How could I preload those fonts to avoid the font flickering on page load?

Did you tried the nuxt module for the fonts?

No, I haven't. Which one do you mean? This one? https://google-fonts.nuxtjs.org/

Yes, that one !

Thank you, but at the end it wasn't necessary. The solution was to keep the useHead part in app.vue, like in my original post, and than copy the fonts to the 'static' folder, because that's where href: '/fonts/font.woff2' points to, and than apply the fonts in the 
There are some performance considerations tho, but if you're happy with your current solution that's also fine!
